# VS Team Services Online 2015 Import wit error tf237090 - does not exist or access is denied

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2015, azure-devops, tfs-workitem

I am attempting to edit our work item template for bugs in Team Services (Visual Studio Online).

I can successfully export a wit in xml, but when I try to import a wit I get the following error:  tf237090 - does not exist or access is denied.

Things I have tried:

1. Check my permissions.  I am running Visual Studio 2015 as administrator.  In the DefaultCollection control panel in Visual Studio Team Services I am a member of the Project Collection Administrators group.
2. Export a wit, then immediately try to import the wit back to the server with no changes.  Still get the error.  This is using the Team Power Tools Process Editor in Visual Studio 2015.
3. Use the command line witadmin tool for Visual Studio 2015 (also ran the command prompt as administrator).  I get the same error even if I export a wit, then try to import the same exact wit.
4. No file locks or open files.  I have created a temporary directory to export the wit to and repeated all of the above steps without editing or opening the wit.xml.
5. Check the forums for the error code, I haven't been able to find any useful information except perhaps 3 year old posts about this not being a feature yet the Visual Studio Team Services help pages indicate it is supported.  Similar questions on StackOverflow that I have searched for are not relevant or go unanswered.

Is this a supported feature in Team Services Online?  What other steps can I use to diagnose and fix this problem?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I found the answer here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2015/07/27/visual-studio-online-process-customization-update.aspx its in the timeline but currently unsupported.

Answer (score 2):

The short of it is that this feature is not supported currently.  More information here:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2015/07/27/visual-studio-online-process-customization-update.aspx